# Sin is not giving the correct value

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-2013

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

Using namespace std;

void main ()
{
   double z,a;
   cout <<"input a"<<endl;
   cin>>a;

   z=sin (a);

   cout <<"z="<<z <<endl;

   system("pause");
}
```

---

When I input the variable a with value of 90 it gives me 0.893997
And when I make the variables int or float it gives the same value

Comment: Maybe read some documentation before using `sin`?

Comment: Please organize your code. It's hard to understand what your are trying to do

Comment: Did you notice that the input of sin is in radians?

Comment: Thanks didn't know that, much appreciated. Sorry for bothering you.

Answer (score 1):

The input of 'sin' is in radians (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sin)

So the answer is, in fact , correct